# I am able to enter ten entries for my TreeSet, but only the last entry prints out

Tags: java, comparator, treeset

The assignment asks for entry of 10 patient records, to include patientId, patientFirstName, patientLastName, patientIllness, and notes; this is to be put into a TreeSet with a Comparator that will abc by last name.

This is the section of code that I am struggling with:

```
public void patientRecord() {
    int i = 0;
    int patientRecords = 10;

    Set<Patient> patientHashSet;

    System.out.println("This program will create ten patient records.");
    System.out.println();

    do {
        getPatientId();

        getPatientFirstName();
        getPatientLastName();
        getPatientIllness();
        getNotes();

        patientHashSet = new TreeSet<>(new PatientComparator());
        patientHashSet.add(new Patient(patientId, patientFirstName, patientLastName, patientIllness, notes));

        i++;
    } while (i < patientRecords);

    for (Patient record : patientHashSet) {

        System.out.println(record.patientId + " " + record.patientLastName + ", " + record.patientFirstName + " "
                + record.patientIllness + " " + record.notes);
        System.out.println("##########################################################################");
    }
}
```

And this is the Comparator code:

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class PatientComparator implements Comparator<Patient> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Patient o1, Patient o2) {
        return o1.patientLastName.compareTo(o2.patientLastName);
    }
}
```

I'm not really sure what it is that I'm doing wrong.  I have also tried placing the "add" into an array, but that produces the same results--only the last patient's information prints out, along with the line of "####".

Comment: Why are you making a new TreeSet on every iteration of the loop? (And why a do-while, rather than a for or a regular while?)

Comment: `patientHashSet = new TreeSet<>` -- **hashSet** = **TreeSet**, seriously? Lets fixed the bugs in your variable names first.

Answer (score 1):

Put this line above the loop

```
patientHashSet = new TreeSet<>(new PatientComparator());
```

In your code, it is written inside the loop, so it is creating a new set on every iteration.

Check the correction.

Comment: When I had placed:   patientHashSet = new TreeSet<>(new PatientComparator()); outside the loop, it then asked for two more entries of the patient's last name (after the entry of patient notes), before moving onto the next patient's id#.

Comment: i didnt get your problem.

Comment: I kept moving patientHashSet = new TreeSet<>(new PatientComparator()); around until it finally worked.  Thank you!